# Identifying current system call number - Linux Kernel 3.4 Android

Tags: android, linux-kernel, system-calls

I need to retrieve the system call number in a piece of code part of the Linux Kernel.

I am using the following function:

```
int sn = syscall_get_nr(current, task_pt_regs(current));
```

Unfortunately, `sn` is always equal to `0`. I am using the ARM function definition since I am compiling the kernel for ARM 32bit.

This code is called from inside `/arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.S` with instraction `bl  my_syscall_begin`, see below snippet:

```
local_restart:
    ldr r10, [tsk, #TI_FLAGS]       @ check for syscall tracing
    stmdb   sp!, {r4, r5}           @ push fifth and sixth args

#ifdef CONFIG_SECCOMP
    tst r10, #_TIF_SECCOMP
    bne __sys_trace
#endif

    tst r10, #_TIF_SYSCALL_WORK     @ are we tracing syscalls?
    bne __sys_trace

#ifdef CONFIG_MY_CONFIG
    stmdb   sp!, {r0-r12}
    bl  my_syscall_begin
    ldmia   sp!, {r0-r12}
#endif

    cmp scno, #NR_syscalls      @ check upper syscall limit
    adr lr, BSYM(ret_fast_syscall)  @ return address
    ldrcc   pc, [tbl, scno, lsl #2]     @ call sys_* routine
```

Comment: In which function you are calling that code?

Comment: I am using a customized version of the kernel and I am calling it from inside char *get_syscall_fname(void)

Comment: And where `get_syscall_fname()` function is being called from? Are you sure you are doing it in syscall context? Because if no -- `0` syscall number seems reasonable enough to me.

Comment: From Kernel code inside /arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.S at local_restart label. @SamProtsenko

Answer (score 0):

Looks like on ARM 3.4 kernel syscall_get_nr only returns a valid syscall number when the thread is being traced and always returns 0 otherwise. Taken from this patch: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromiumos/third_party/kernel/+/321802. You would probably need to make the code change shown on that page for it to work.